# vis.js multiple group membership

Tags: vis.js

Is it possible for a node to belong in multiple groups?  Can there be multiple links between two nodes?  Further can links belong to groups?

Example:
An ethernet switch has multiple VLANs (Groups?).
Each switch will have links for each VLAN.
A switch (node) might have multiple links to another switch (node), but only one per VLAN (group).  In reality multiple links could exist, but this could be represented by link strengths.

The goal is to be able to interactively analyze how switches connect together on a per vlan basis.  Is there a straight forward way to do this?  The documentation seemed to suggest a node can only belong to one group.

Comment: You should ask one question per post. This makes it easier for people to find it and to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question (multiple group membership), it appears nodes can belong only to one group. I haven't found any mention saying otherwise.

As for the second question (more links between two nodes), yes, there can:

```
{from: 1, to: 3},
{from: 1, to: 3},
```

http://screencloud.net/v/kHGBf

As for the third question (can edges belong to groups): they can't. A group attribute has no effect, even if present.